# In Magento2 How to add block in layout xml file

Tags: magento2

I want offer button at very top of my website. For that i want to create phtml file and want to call it in magento2 layout xml file. Please tell me how can i achieve this in magento2?

Answer (score 5):

Magento 2 call "cms block" in XML file :

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_name">
  <arguments>
    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_identifier</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
```

Magento 2 call "cms block" in Phtml file :

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

Magento 2 call "cms block" in CMS Content :

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```

It's working fine....

Answer (score 0):

Try this: All layput and template files should me inside View folder

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
<container name="root" label="Root">
    <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View\XYZ" name="module.edit.tab.xyz" template="Namespace_Module::/template_path/abc.phtml"/>
</container>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to only replace with your block identifier...**

> here is my block identifier = "product_view_right_sidebar" ==
>   "Your_block_identifier"

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product_view_right_sidebar">
        <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">product_view_right_sidebar</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```